# How to find number of windows with the same title bar or class?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to get an integer value for the number of windows running with a specific windows class/title. Is there a function that can do that? I've tried `FindWindow` but it doesn't seem to go through ALL the windows.

An example of what I am trying to do would be finding the number of Windows a user has open with the "Visual Studio" class.

Comment: The Windows terminology for finding or iterating over multiple "things" is *enumeration*. From that it's easy to find the [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) function.

Comment: `EnumWindows` is a starting point. You'll still need to request the class name ([`GetClassNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassnamew)) for identification, and—depending on your requirements—iterate over child windows ([`EnumChildWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows)

> Enumerates all **top-level** windows on the screen by passing the handle
> to each window, in turn, to an application-defined callback function.

You can use [GetClassName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassnamew), [GetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw) to retrieve the name of the class and the text of the specified window's title bar respectively. See the [ScreenCaptureforHWND](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/a59e7586c0bd1a967e1e25f6ca0363e20151afe5/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND/ScreenCaptureforHWND/Win32WindowEnumeration.h#L90) example.
For the others, as @IInspectable said, use [EnumChildWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows). But as far as Visual Studio is concerned, *EnumWindows* is enough.